# imshowpair function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Is it possible to use `imshowpair` function in MATLAB to display images next to each other instead of over one another?

So far I have:

```
figure;
imshowpair(imgA, imgB, 'diff');
```

I have about 100 images I would like to display. Is it possible?

Comment: You can just plot images the regular way, but using `subplot`. One figure with a 100 subplots is a lot though

Comment: so you want to display 100 images side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is possible.

```
imshowpair(im1, im2, 'montage')
```

It only displays 2 images, though. If you need to display many images of the same size use `montage` or the newer `imtile` function.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use

```
newImg = cat(2,img1,img2);
```